# Are there any signatures based on matrix multiplication with noise?

Tags: signature, homomorphic-signatures

Are there any signatures based on matrix multiplication with noise? Representing the message as a matrix and multiplying with some randomness coming from another matrix such that the signature itself is a matrix?

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/537.pdf ? Also https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/755

Comment: Lamport One Way signatures use a matrix as rivate and public key, but the input and output are no matrix. Do you have a special case where you need the input and ouptu to be a matrix? Or what is the motivation for this? There are some gutter based cryptographical primitives though but I am not fully familiar with them. And out of curiosity, one can format any matrix into a string, what is the desired advantage of the matrix? Some hash functions use matrix multiplications during hashing to introduce artificial noise though...

Comment: My motivation is non-cummutative signature aggregation

Comment: Sounds to me like McEliece, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McEliece_cryptosystem

Answer (score 2):

There are two major families of signature schemes that bear some resemblance what you described.

### Code-based signatures: Courtois–Finiasz–Sendrier, or CFS

The [CFS family of signature schemes](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480158.pdf) is based on code-based cryptography [first introduced by Robert McEliece in 1978](https://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report2/42-44/44N.PDF) and [dualized by Niederreiter](http://real-j.mtak.hu/7997/).  We work with *binary linear codes*, of length $n$ and rank $k$ correcting up to $t$ errors.

In the error-correcting code scenario, a sender with a $k$-bit message $m$ redundantly encodes it as an $n$-bit codeword $c$ from a $k$-dimensional subspace of all $n$-bit strings, and sends it along a noisy channel; the receiver, on receiving a possibly modified message $c' = c + e$, can uniquely recover $c$ as the codeword nearest to $c'$ as long as the error pattern $e$ has no more than $t$ bits set, *i.e.* as long as the Hamming weight of $e$ is at most $t$.

The *generator matrix* of a linear code is a $k$-by-$n$ matrix $G$ that that transforms $k$-bit messages to $n$-bit codewords: $c = G m$.  The *parity-check matrix* of a linear code is an $n$-by-$(n-k)$ matrix $K$ that transforms $n$-bit strings to $(n-k)$-bit **syndromes**.  An $n$-bit string is a codeword in the code if and only if its syndrome is zero: $K c = 0$, and $H c' = K\cdot(c + e) = K c + K e = K e$.  The [**syndrome decoding problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoding_methods#Syndrome_decoding) is to find $e$ given $K e$.  **The premise of CFS signatures is that finding the noise given a syndrome given only the parity-check matrix $K$ seems to be difficult without additional information about the structure of the linear code.**

**Parameters.**
Bit sizes $n$, $k$, $t$ for a family of binary linear codes, usually [binary Goppa codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Goppa_code) (other proposals like [Reed–Solomon codes have been broken](https://doi.org/10.1515/dma.1992.2.4.439), although there are new candidates, *e.g.* Reed–Muller codes in the pqsigRM submission to [NIST PQCRYPTO](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/post-quantum-cryptography/round-1-submissions)), and a random function $H\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb F_2^{n-k}$ from messages to syndromes.

**Public keys.**
Alice's public key is the parity-check matrix $K$ of a binary linear code of length $n$ and rank $k$ correcting up to $t$ errors.

**Signatures.**
A signature by Alice on a message $m$ is an error pattern $e \in \mathbb F_2^n$ such that $K e = H(m)$.  **That is, a signature is *the noise* whose multiplication by a parity-check matrix yields a syndrome that is the hash of a message.**

**Private keys and signing.**
Too complicated to fit in the margins of this crypto.se post; see [McBits](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#mcbits) for a modern implementation strategy of CFS signatures and Niederreiter KEM, and [Classic McEliece](https://classic.mceliece.org/nist.html) for a NIST PQCRYPTO submission based on it (but KEM-only, no signatures), which also have concrete parameter suggestions for reasonable post-quantum security levels.  (The pqsigRM submission to NIST PQCRYPTO may have some implementation ideas too, but its supporting documentation makes no mention of side channel attacks or constant-time algorithms, and a brief look at the code makes me suspicious.)

### Lattice-based signatures

Let $q$ be a prime, and let $F$ be the field $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$.  Fix a secret vector $s \in F^n$, a sample of uniform random vectors $a_i \in F^n$, and a sample of errors $e_i \in \mathbb Z$ with some distribution $\chi$

The ***computational* learning with errors problem**, [introduced by Regev in 2005](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1060590.1060603), is to find $s$ given the sample $(a_i, \langle a_i, s\rangle + e_i) \in F^n \times F$ with nonnegligible probability.

The ***decisional* learning with errors problem** is to distinguish it from $(a_i, v_i)$ for uniform random $v_i \in F$.  There are a few variants on the theme: for example, in the **ring learning with errors problem**, we replace the vector space $F^n$ by the ring $F/(x^n + 1)$ when $n$ is a power of two, or $F/(\Phi(x))$ for some polynomial $\Phi(x) \in F[x]$, which was [introduced by Lyubashevsky, Peikert, and Regev in 2010 to admit much smaller parameters](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-13190-5_1).

This is a sketch of the [Lyubahsevsky's learning with errors signature scheme](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-29011-4_43), derived from the same [Fiat–Shamir transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_heuristic) used to derive [Schnorr signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature), and on which newer systems such as the NIST PQCRYPTO submission qTESLA are based.

**Parameters.**
Field $F$; dimensions $n$, $m$, and $k$; bound $d$; bounded distribution $\chi$ on $\mathbb Z^m$; a standard $n$-by-$m$ matrix $A$ in $F$; and a random function $H\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \{-1,0,+1\}^k$ such that $\lVert H(M)\rVert_1$ is bounded.

**Public keys.**
Alice's public key is an $n$-by-$k$ matrix $T$ in $F$.

**Signatures.**
A signature by Alice on a message $\mu$ is a pair of $z \in \mathbb Z^m$ and $c \in \mathbb Z^k$ such that

1. $\lVert z\rVert^2 = \sum_i {z_i}^2$ is small, and
2. $c = H(\underline{A z_q - T c_q} \mathbin\Vert \mu)$, where $z_q$ and $c_q$ are the componentwise projections of $z$ and $c$ onto $F = \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$, and the underline is some canonical bit string encoding of $F$.

(For the technical details of what ‘small’ means, see the paper.)

**Private key and signing.**
Alice's private key is a secret $m$-by-$k$ matrix $S$ in $\mathbb Z$ whose elements are chosen uniformly at random from integers at most $d$ in absolute value.  Let $S_q$ be the componentwise projection of the matrix $S$ onto $F$.  Alice computes her public key by $T = A S_q$.  (With an appropriate transformation of $A$, this is not far from the form of the learning-with-errors problem.)

To sign a message $\mu$, Alice draws $y \in \mathbb Z^m$ from $\chi$,  computes $c = H(\underline{A y_q} \mathbin\Vert \mu)$ and $z = S c + y$, and, with some rejection sampling on $z$, reveals $(c, z)$.

This satisfies criterion (1) of signatures because of the bounds on $S$, $c = H(\cdots)$, and $y \sim \chi$.

This satisfies criterion (2) of signatures because $A z_q - T c_q = A S_q c_q + A y_q - A S_q c_q = A y_q$, so $c = H(\underline{A y_q} \mathbin\Vert \mu) = H(\underline{A z_q - T c_q} \mathbin\Vert \mu)$.

Filling in details is left as an exercise for a less tired ossifrage than this one, preferably when day is not breaking.